# Split a string on an integer

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I need to take a string 'list' as input and format it accordingly. Here is some example input:

`string = "This is the input:1. A list element;2. Another element;3. And another one."`

And I'd like the output to be a list in the following format:

`list " ["This is the input:", "A list element;", "Another element;", "And another one."]`

I have tried doing the following:

`list = string.split('(\d+). ')`

Hoping that it would split on all integers followed by a full stop and a space, but that doesn't seem to work: only a single element list is returned, indicating that none of the split criteria is found.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: alecxe has answered how to do it; what you're doing wrong is a) `string.split()` doesn't take regexes, only literal text, and b) `.` in regex is a special character which matches anything, so a digit followed by *a literal dot* needs the `.` escaped with a backslash.

Comment: Thanks for the input - kicking myself for not escaping the `.` but it's somewhat comforting to know that it wouldn't have worked with `\d` anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`re.split()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) splitting by `:` or `;` followed by one or more digits followed by a dot and a space:

```
>>> re.split(r"[:;]\d+\.\s", s)
['This is the input', 'A list element', 'Another element', 'And another one.']
```

To keep the `:` and `;` inside the splits, you can use a [positive lookbehind check](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
>>> re.split(r"(?<=:|;)\d+\.\s", s)
['This is the input:', 'A list element;', 'Another element;', 'And another one.']
```